# batch extract and delete archives, how to delete .part*.rar

Tags: batch-file

I have been using this script to extract and delete archives but it's not handling archives named .part##.rar correctly for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
for /r %%r in (*.zip *.7z *.rar *.ace) do 7z x -y "%%r" >nul && del "%%r" && echo unpacked "%%~nxr"
```

---

edit: I decided to build this into a separate script that handles all archives in a single folder `%1`

```
:security
cd /d "%~1" || echo no valid directory defined && exit /b
attrib -s -h *.* >nul
dir *.rar *.zip *.7z *.ace >nul 2>nul || exit /b

:extract
for %%r in (*.zip.001 *.7z.001 *.tar.001) do (
    7z x -y "%%r" >nul && recycle -f "%%r" && echo unpacked "%%~nxr"
    if exist "%%r" echo unpack failed, maybe the disk is full? && exit /b
    recycle -f "%%~dpn.???" && echo multipart archives "%%~dpn.???" recycled
)

for %%r in (*.part1.rar *.part01.rar *.part001.rar) do (
    7z x -y "%%r" >nul && recycle -f "%%r" && echo unpacked "%%~nxr"
    if exist "%%r" echo unpack failed, maybe the disk is full? && exit /b
    rem need a way to delete multipart volumes here
)

for %%r in (*.rar *.zip *.7z *.ace *.tar) do (
    7z x -y "%%r" >nul && recycle -f "%%r" && echo unpacked "%%~nxr"
    if exist "%%r" echo unpack failed, maybe the disk is full? && exit /b
    if /i "%%~xr"==".rar" if exist "%%~dpnr.r00" recycle -f "%%~dpnr.r??" && echo multipart archives "%%~dpn.r??" recycled
)

goto security
```

I need help with deleting the remaining files in the middle stack.

Comment: Does the directory/filename contains special characters? What exactly are the `##` bits?

Comment: `.part##.rar` seems to denote a part of a multi-volume archive, so I guess you need to specify the first part when extracting, as it could fail when specifying another one. Anyway, what is the exact error you receive?

Comment: those `##` part (numbering of a multi-volume archive) can't be extracted on their own (they are only parts of the whole). Its meant to extract the first part (that without numbers), which then opens the other volumes internally.

Comment: Yes these are traditionally (in order) `.rar, .r00, .r01` and so on and the new numbering method is `.part01.rar, .part02.rar` and so on. 7z seems to name any multipart as `.7z.001, .7z.002` and so on, even if it's regular zip.. `.zip.001, .zip.002` AND I'm not sure but I think rars can also be `.part1.rar` and `.part001.rar` depending on the total number of splits. I think it's good enough for me to get the `.part##.rar` ones handles out of all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second code with expanded loops, here is how to delete the partial `.rar` archives (loop 2):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%R in (*.part1.rar *.part01.rar *.part001.rar) do (
   REM notice uppercase R used!
   REM process first archive "name.part01.rar"...like posted  

   REM now delete all partial archives of this name
   REM isolate archive name
   for %%F in ("%%~nR") do set "files=%%~nF"
   if exist "!files!.part*.rar" ECHO del /Q "!files!.part*.rar"
)
```

As usual please test this and then remove the `ECHO` statement.
Notes:
1- in your first loop (handling `.zip.001` etc.), you need to use `%%dpnr` instead of `%%dpn`. Using uppercase loop variables help spotting this kind of error (`%R` instead of `%r`).
2- `dir *.rar *.zip *.7z *.ace >nul 2>nul || exit /b` should be `dir *.rar *.zip *.7z *.ace *.tar >nul 2>nul || exit /b` to check for tarfiles as well.

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing quotes!

Answer (score 0):

This will attempt to narrow down the exception as much as possible to the pattern used, using a Regular Expression:

```
for /F %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *.zip *.7z *.rar *.ace ^|findstr /REIV /C:"\.part[0-9][0-9]*\.rar"') do @(7z x -y "%%f" >nul && del "%%f" && echo unpacked "%%~nxf")
```

Comment: It's not unpacking them, just skipping. Investigating now.

Comment: I can't make much sense of this so I decided to expand this job into a separate script to handle the different types. See my updated question.

Comment: This code is meant to skip all "part" + numeric archives as they are only implicitely unpacked when you unpack the 'main' archive. Is that not the case?

Comment: But it also skips the main archive `.part01.rar`